# Where's BOARD_AVB_ENABLE flag? (Verified Boot Android (AVB))

Tags: android, security, android-8.0-oreo

So, I've downloaded the source code of Android Oreo 8.0. I want to enable the Verified Boot using this flag, and also putting different flags (like `BOARD_AVB_ALGORITHM`) to configure this. But I can't find which file this configurations are.

Anyone know this? Thanks!

Comment: whether you found?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find it here:
android\device**\BoardConfig.mk

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33665445)